# useEffect trace origin for change

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where a local state is being updated at multiple places.

I also have a `useEffect` hook on state.

I want to know which change resulted into calling the useEffect function. Is there any way to traceback from hook where the event was originated?

Here is trace which does not clearly say where the event was originated

```
trace log
   in App (at src/​index.js:9)
r @ backend.js:8032
eval @ App.js? [sm]:11
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:19731
commitPassiveHookEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19769
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22853
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22820
eval @ react-dom.development.js:22699
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:597
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:552
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:164
```

I tried adding console.log and console trace inside useEffect but it does not show which setState calls it.

Here is sample code

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Here I want to know if #1 or #2 caused this event for debugging purposes');
}, [state]);


const onClick1 = () => {
   setState(1); //#1 first call of setState
}

const onClick2 = () => {
   setState(2); //#2 second call of setState
}
```

This is just a sample snippet but the problem in real time scenario is much more complex since I have at least 50 places where I am calling `setState` which I wish to debug in useEffect to determine which `setState` actually messed up my data.

Here is a fiddle which replicates the behaviour: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bush-m6jdd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to that? My question is around debugging exceptions I see happening from hooks. Without stacktraces, it's hard to debug them.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: create a wrapper on `setState` and debug/log such wrapper. Make sure `setState` is never called from any other place.

I think by design React decouples the setting of the state and at the actions that might result from it. IMHO it does so to force a proper design of the application (kind of publish-subscribe mechanism), but it makes it hard to solve the problem you are facing (e.g. checking the call stack in the `useEffect` you will not see the `setState` that caused the re-render).